# how do i create a my own inplementation of pkcs11.h

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, smartcard, pkcs#11, opensc

I have a smart card that i want to use later such that, i can retrieve the certificate inside and use that to sign a PDFs or what not with digital signature.

so i was trying to use [opensc](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki) for that, but turns out the card is not supported there,
so i would like to create my own middleware specifically for this card...
( i am new to all this so hoping you guys could help me out)

> when i use ***opensc-tool --name*** in the terminal
>
> > it outputs **unsupported card**,

and

> when i use ***opensc-tool --atr*** in the terminal
>
> > it outputs **ATR: 3B D5 18 FF 81 91 FE 1F C3 80 73 C8 21 10 0A** of the card

> > > > > > > **NOTE: you need to build and install Opensc before trying these commands in your terminal**

a good example (or what i think it is) is [pkcs11-tool.c](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/blob/master/src/tools/pkcs11-tool.c)

also, if anyone got any other way of solving this, please do specify, any help is appreciated.